# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' on djangorestframework_simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I was trying to follow this quick start from djangorestframework-simplejwt documentation with link https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

But I have problem when try to obtain token, and always return this error
`'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

[image]

**Edited:**
This my code on urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views
from core.views import HelloView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('hello/', HelloView.as_view(), name='hello'),
]
```

settings.py

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
...
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class HelloView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        content = {'message': 'Hello, World!'}
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: Where are you using the token generated by jwt for authentication? @MasDimas

Answer (score 26):

Downgrading PyJWT did the job for me.

To achieve that, change the corresponding line in your `requirements.txt` to

```
PyJWT==v1.7.1
```

or install the specified package with:

```
pip install pyjwt==v1.7.1
```

Comment: Downgrading libraries is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Remove .decode('utf-8') in "/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py" like

```
# /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py
def jwt_encode_handler(payload):
key = api_settings.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY or jwt_get_secret_key(payload)
return jwt.encode(
    payload,
    key,
    api_settings.JWT_ALGORITHM
)#.decode('utf-8') ==> delete this
```

[jwt2.3.0-utils-encode_handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPabs.png)

As you installed simple-jwt, jwt has been upgraded to version-2.3.0 from 1.7.1(maybe).
and by this,

[jwt2.3.0-api_jwt-encode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LE0S.png)

"-> str:" has been added at the method "encode", and this means "encode" returns "str".

so we don't need .decode('utf-8') anymore in utils.py in rest_framework_jwt.

and if you run server again you may encounter the problem below.

except jwt.ExpiredSignature:
rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: module 'jwt' has no attribute 'ExpiredSignature'

you can fix this as below,

```
# /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py
try:
    payload = jwt_decode_handler(jwt_value)
except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError: # ExpiredSignature => no more exists
    msg = _('Signature has expired.')
    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
except jwt.DecodeError:
    msg = _('Error decoding signature.')
    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
```

[jwt2.3.0-authentication-except](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Soq.png)

this problem has occured because the jwt-version has been upgraded to 2.3.0, and ExpiredSignature doesn't exist anymore.

But we recommend you to downgrade jwt version to 1.7.1 as we don't know all the changes made by upgrade.

[jwt2.3.0-init.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0ldk.png)

[jwt1.7.1-init.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n69Vl.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the updated version of PyJWT (2.6.0), refer to the [documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#example-usage).

It shows how to encode and decode with the latest version of PyJWT.

```
jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, "secret", algorithms=["HS256"])
```

Notice, how you pass in the encoded `jwt`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this fixed mine

```
pip install decode==0.7.1
```